# How to pull strings and then concatenate in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below is an example of the data I currently have. I would like to create additional cells that go as follows Brandon 1, Brandon 2, and Brandon 3. And so on

Current Data

```
       A        B 
1    Brandon   123
```

Ideally my output/result would look like this.

```
       A      
1    Brandon 1
2    Brandon 2  
3    Brandon 3
```

I tried the following which did not work: `=concatenate (DB," ",textsplit(dc, " "))`

Comment: `TEXTSPLIT()` can't split on empty string and I also am not sure why you thought splitting on a space would work. Either way, try `=A1&" "&MID(B1,SEQUENCE(LEN(B1)),1)`. On a sidenote: It would be awesome to be able to split on empty string to seperate each character, I've allready send feedback about it. Fingers crossed.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, I shared the same, but deleted, because what happens when there is few more data below the first cell `Brandon   123` how will it work. If you share one example, because I am not able to think how to do it, I was thinking like `Power Query` should be the right tool here

Comment: Not sure what you mean @MayukhBhattacharya

Comment: @JvdV Sir, I meant to say that, like in cell `A2` it is showin `Brandon`  and in cell `B2` its `123` alright, again in cell `A3` there is `Jason` and in cell `B3` it is `1234` and so on so forth

Comment: Something like `=LET(X,A1:A3&" "&MID(B1:B3,SEQUENCE(1,MAX(LEN(B1:B3))),1),Y,TOCOL(IF(X=A1:A3&" ","",X)),FILTER(Y,Y<>""))` maybe, but I can't really test nomore since I'm out for the rest of my saturday.

Comment: @JvdV Sir, worked perfectly like a charm, no doubt!